# How to get rid of everything but the curve using image processing?

Tags: image-processing

Originally the image was of a photograph of a fish. As I need to compute the slope of the curve, I am trying to get rid of every detail in the image except for the dark bold curve that runs all along the body (without the tail fin or caudal fin).

I did a log transform followed by NevatiaBabu.

And this is the result:

[[image: binary image of a fish]]

Then I did dilation and erosion. I got this:
[image: binary image of a fish eroded]

But I really want to get rid of all the extra details without using any manual handling. This is supposed to be redone automatically afterward. So any suggestions would be appreciated...

Comment: Is the image in your post BW or greyscale? Any code you can share? Or the original picture?

Comment: It's in grayscale. The real image can be found via this link [link]<https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-_ftWtPUwNfs/Wj3zBOpR-xI/AAAAAAAAD9g/numnDt6lTkckuqObQ78cqZLsOenl_zKLQCLcBGAs/s400/Yellowfin%2BTuna%2BLoin%2BPrecooked%2B-%2BYellowfin%2BTuna.jpg>

Comment: Look into Hough transformation for curve detection. E.g. [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4981/b27926192cad7652264027612b607972d3ad.pdf) is a nice paper on that topic.